# Mudar valor da variável dentro de classe anônima

Tags: java, android

Gostaria de saber o motivo que sempre que dentro de uma classe anonima tento mudar o valor de uma variável "externa" ela não, muda continua na mesma. Teria algo similar que poderia fazer que fosse dar o mesmo resultado?

Usei o **Thread** como exemplo, mas em qualquer classe anônima isso acontece. (Inclusive no Android)

```
public class Teste {

    public boolean umIgualUm = false;

    public Teste() {
        fazerAlgo();
    }

    public void fazerAlgo() {

        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                if (1 == 1) {
                    System.out.println("Entra aqui");
                    umIgualUm = true;
                }
            }
        }.start();

        System.out.println(umIgualUm); //Exibe false

    }

}
```

Exemplo Android

```
public class UsuarioDAO {

    public boolean metodoDeuCerto = false;

    public UsuarioDAO(){}

    public boolean cadastrarUsuario(Usuario usuario) {

        ParseUser parseUser = new ParseUser();
        parseUser.setUsername(usuario.getNome());
        parseUser.setEmail(usuario.getEmail());
        parseUser.setPassword(usuario.getSenha());

        parseUser.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                if(e == null) { //Quer dizer que deu certo
                    metodoDeuCerto = true;
                }else{
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    metodoDeuCerto = false;
                }

            }

        });

        return metodoDeuCerto;

    }
}
```

Comment: Na verdade acredito que seja por conta da sincronia em que as coisas dentro da classe anônima acontecem. Como no exemplo postado ao startar a thread o System.out.println é executado logo em seguida e não deu tempo de terminar o processo do run()

Comment: Tem a certeza que isso acontece no caso de não ser "numa Thread"? No uso de "uma Thread" acontece porque quando  linha `System.out.println(umIgualUm);` é executada a linha `umIgualUm = true;` (pode) não (ter sido)foi executada.

Comment: Com qual outra classe anonima eu poderia testar?

Comment: No Android pode testar por exemplo num `OnClickListener`, atribuído a um botão.

Comment: Coloquei o exemplo do Android, que está acontecendo realmente.

Comment: Nesse exemplo acontece o mesmo. O método `done()` é chamado, pela implementação de `signUpInBackground()`, após a linha `return metodoDeuCerto;` ter sido executada.

Comment: E como fazer para poder dar um retorno para o usuario se deu certo ou não o cadastro? Pois já que não posso fazer assim, nem dar o return por dentro do metodo da classe anonima (claro). Como fazer?

Comment: Depende de como quer informar o usuário. No entanto, qualquer que seja essa forma, ela tem de ser feita dentro do método `done()` ou em um método chamado por ele.

Comment: Precisava informar essa o usuario, retornar ou a Exception ou um boolean, mas precisava retornar pq não é essa classe que irá cuidar de avisar o usuario com alguam mensagem.

Comment: Nesse caso passe o SignUpCallback ao método `cadastrarUsuario()` ou, talvez melhor, crie um nova interface/classe para receber o resultado.

Comment: Teria alguma forma de esperar o SignUpCallback  terminar para poder retornar?

Comment: Se de facto é isso que quer, pode, veja a [documentação](http://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-Android/api/com/parse/ParseUser.html#signUpInBackground())

Comment: Certo, mas ainda não entendi como esperar o meu thread "principal" fazer esperar por esse em especifico. Desculpa, não sou tão experiente com java.

Comment: É por isso que eu não lhe vou dizer como. Não quero contribuir para que você comece a aprender de forma errada :)

Comment: Bom andei pesquisando e nao consegui nada tao referente. Queria a ideia de pegar o Thread da classe UsuarioDAO  e pedir para esperar ou algo assim. Tenho a ideia de usar o metodo join() mas nao sei de que forma exatamente. Sinceramente, consegue me dar uma ajuda, gostaria de gazer isso logo, estou ficando aflito.

Answer (score 0):

Há dois problemas aqui:

1. O método `start` pode demorar para de fato iniciar a nova thread. Com isso o `System.out` pode acabar executando primeiro.
2. Variáveis podem ficar em caches específicas de threads, e com isso, threads diferentes podem enxergar valores diferentes para a mesma variável ao mesmo tempo. Para contornar-se este problema pode-se usar sincronização ou fazer as variáveis serem `volatile` (algo que instrui a JVM a não permitir que elas sejam mantidas em caches separadas por threads). Uma outra possibilidade é usar um `AtomicBoolean`.

O problema não tem nenhuma relação com o fato de a variável estar sendo acessada de dentro da classe anônima. O problema é ela estar sendo acessada de outra thread.

Se você vê esse problema acontecendo quando usa uma classe anônima que não seja uma `Thread`, solicito que mostre esse código.

Quanto ao seu segundo código, o método`signUpInBackground` cria uma thread nova para executar o que está na classe anônima, o que significa que o método `cadastrarUsuario` executará o `return` sem esperar o `signUpInBackground` ser concluído.

De fato, o método [`signUpInBackground()`](http://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-Android/api/com/parse/ParseUser.html#signUpInBackground()) retorna uma `Task<Void>`.

O que é a classe [`Task`](http://boltsframework.github.io/docs/android/bolts/Task.html) de acordo com a documentação?

> Represents the result of an asynchronous operation.

Traduzindo para o português:

> Representa o resultado de uma operação assíncrona.

O que é uma operação assíncrona?

Significa que o processo que a inicia **não aguarda pelo seu término**, que produzirá algum resultado apenas em um futuro incerto. Ou seja, o seu método `cadastrarUsuario` não está de fato cadastrando um usuário, está apenas pedindo que um usuário seja cadastrado **e retornando imediatamente**. Note que isso não implica que o usuário foi de fato cadastrado em momento algum. Você teria que esperar a `Task` terminar para saber isso.

Nos dois casos, o problema é que o que aparece no corpo da classe anônima, só é executado muito tempo depois do método principal já ter retornado, e ainda por cima é executado em outra thread.

Comment: Então, criei esse exemplo somente em Java, mas estou na realidade trabalhando em um projeto Android, que usa também uma classe anonima (não é Thread) e acontece a mesma coisa.  O exemplo em Java criei para simplificar. E por exemplo, se eu quisesse usar em vez do boolean, fizer isso "Excpetion ex = null", depois quando eu tentasse modificar, ele continuaria como null, mesmo passando algo diferente. Posso mandar feito em Android, usando o Parse.

Comment: Citei exemplo do Android

Comment: @Hamon Resposta editada.

Comment: Certo e como posso fazer o retorno certo? O método até cadastra no banco de dados o usuário, mas não chega a mudar boolean (que já temos a explicação para isso), mas como faria para poder dar um retorno, da melhor forma possivel? Sem muita perda de otimização

Comment: @Hamon , você precisará programar assincronamente.

Comment: Desculpa, sou meio leigo, como?

Answer (score 0):

Como já disseram antes, você não pode mudar o valor de uma variável dentro da thread e testá-la logo em seguida. Provavelmente o seu teste (if, println, ou o que seja) irá ser chamado antes da thread ser iniciada.

Uma das formas corretas a se trabalhar, seria: (Com seu próprio exemplo)

```java
public class Teste {

    public Teste() {
        fazerAlgo();
    }

    public void fazerAlgo() {

        new Thread() {
            public void run() {                                       
                System.out.println("Entra aqui");

                if (1 == 1) {
                    metodoDeuCerto();
                } else {
                    metodoNaoDeuCerto();
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }

    public void metodoDeuCerto() {
        System.out.println("Deu certo!");
    }


    public void metodoNaoDeuCerto() {
        System.out.println("Nao deu certo!"); 
    }
}
```

**(EDITADO)**

Exemplo Android:

```java
public class UsuarioDAO {

    private SignupListener listener;

    public UsuarioDAO(){}

    public void cadastrarUsuario(Usuario usuario) {

        ParseUser parseUser = new ParseUser();
        parseUser.setUsername(usuario.getNome());
        parseUser.setEmail(usuario.getEmail());
        parseUser.setPassword(usuario.getSenha());

        parseUser.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                if(e == null) {
                   if ( listener != null ) {
                       listener.deuCerto();
                   }
                }else{
                   e.printStackTrace();
                   if ( listener != null ) {
                       listener.naoDeuCerto();
                   }
                }

            }

        });
    }

    public void setSignupListener(SignupListener signupListener) {
        this.listener = signupListener; 
    }

    public interface SignupListener {
        void deuCerto();
        void naoDeuCerto();
    }
}
```

// Exemplo da Activity chamando o UsuarioDAO

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity); 

        Usuario usuario = new Usuario();
        usuario.setUserName("usuario");
        usuario.setEmail("usuario@email.com");
        usuario.setPassword("senha");

        UsuarioDAO dao = new UsuarioDAO();
        dao.setSignupListener(signupListener);
        dao.cadastrarUsuario(usuario);

    }

    private UsuarioDAO.SignupListener signupListener = new UsuarioDAO.SignupListener {
        @Override
        public void deuCerto() {
           //DO SOMETHING
        }

        @Override
        public void naoDeuCerto() {
           //DO SOMETHING
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Eu precisava de um retorno no metodo, pq o metodo que recebe esse retorno avisa o usuario

Comment: O problema é que você está usando uma classe DAO para fazer algo que não devia, que é o signup. Mas não vou entrar nesse mérito já que a pergunta não foi essa. Mas isso é facilmente contornável criando o seu próprio listener. Vou editar a resposta do exemplo com android para você ver como poderia ficar.

Comment: Mas o DAO nao faz os acessos ao banco? Inclusive o cadastro do usuario no.banco? Ou estou fazendo errado?

Comment: Da forma como está o exemplo, parece que você está fazendo algo a mais nesse signUpInBackground(), esperando a resposta de alguma api, etc. De qualquer forma eu atualizei a resposta. Essa é uma das milhares de respostas possíveis para o seu problema.

Comment: Achei que seria interessante esperar essa thread terminar, dai sim conseguir retornar. So que nao estou conseguindo entender como posso usar o join() para que o thread main espere ate que o outro termine

Comment: Você não pode fazer isso na main thread do Android, isso só vai fazer com que sua aplicação pare de responder e consequentemente poderá travar seu app.

Comment: Mas entao esperar a thread do signup terminar para ai sim ele poder retornar, tem como?